# .htaccess rewrites for language redirection, two versions of the page, keeping address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

hopefully someone can give me a hint with this.

What i mean to do is to redirect visits depending on both the browser language and the url entered (wether or not /v2 is included in it). I want to keep the original url in the address bar so i understand i can only use internal apache redirection, not 301.

```
URL            BROWSER LANGUAGE    INTERNAL REDIRECTION
domain.com           en                 en.html
domain.com/v2        en                 en_v2.html
domain.com           es                 es.html
domain.com/v2        es                 es_v2.html
domain.com           other              en.html
domain.com/v2        other              en_v2.html
```

So this is what i have tried in .htaccess:

```
#mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine on

#Default language redirection
RewriteRule ^.*$ en.html
RewriteRule ^.*?v2$ en_v2.html

#Redirection by Language en
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ en.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*?v2$ en_v2.html

#Redirection by Language es
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ es.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*?v2$ es_v2.html [L]
```

All the html files are in the root folder, same as the .htaccess file. In this way I'm trying to make some rewrites "overwrite" a previous rewrite, for example

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ es.html
```

which matches everything, would be overwritten by

```
RewriteRule ^.*?v2$ es_v2.html
```

in case /v2 is in the URL. I'm not sure it works like that though.

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**: Solved, this is the final version:

```
#mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine on

#Allow direct access to html files
RewriteRule ^en(_v2)?\.html - [L]
RewriteRule ^es(_v2)?\.html - [L]

#Without this the css and other files are redirected and won't load properly
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$ - [L]

#Redirection by Language
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (es) [NC]
RewriteRule ^v2$ es_v2.html [L]

#Redirection by Language
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (es) [NC]
RewriteRule .* es.html [L]

#Defaults
RewriteRule ^v2$ en_v2.html [L]
RewriteRule .* en.html [L]
```

Comment: Seems it would be best to treat this as `es` and "The Rest of the World" since `en` is the same as `other`. Deal with `es` and if it's not that, then deal with everything else.

Comment: sure! i added the rest of the world part afterwards without giving it a second thought, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example.

```
#mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^en(_v2)?\.html - [L]

#Redirection by Language en
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*?v2$ en_v2.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ en.html [L]

#Redirection by Language es
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*?v2$ es_v2.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ es.html [L]

#Default language redirection
RewriteRule ^.*?v2$ en_v2.html [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ en.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! this helped a lot, i edited the original post with the final working version.